# WPF BackgroundColor

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

I want to give the user of my WPF-application the chance to change the backgroundcolor of the application. For that, he has a combobox with some values:

```
        cbSetBackground.Items.Add("green");
        cbSetBackground.Items.Add("red");
        cbSetBackground.Items.Add("blue");
        cbSetBackground.Items.Add("yellow");
```

Now, with the Click-Event, I have to put the backgroundcolor to the selected color. I tried it like this

```
this.Background = Brushes. + cbSetBackground.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

For sure, this isn´t working. 
How can I manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give this one a try:

```
BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();  
this.Background=  (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom(cbSetBackground.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

**OR**

```
BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();  
this.Background=  (Brush)bc.ConvertFromString(cbSetBackground.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

**OR**

```
Brush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromName(cbSetBackground.SelectedItem.ToString()));
this.Background=myBrush;
```

Check out the `BrushConverter` class here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushconverter.convertfromstring.aspx

Comment: great thank you. Do you know, how I can set this backgroundcolor to my whole application? Do I have to commit it in the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the BrushConverter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushconverter.aspx).

```
BrushConverter conv = new BrushConverter();
SolidColorBrush brush = conv.ConvertFromString(cbSetBackground.SelectedItem.ToString()) as SolidColorBrush;
this.Background = brush;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
string colorStr = cbSetBackground.SelectedItem.ToString();
Color c = (Color)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Color)).ConvertFromString(colorStr);

this.Background = c;
```

But you might need to change the first character to uppercase.